# Does Dynamics ERP has built in REST api and can it acceess through web

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

Currently I'm in evaluation process to identify Dynamics ERP system capabilities. I need following information,

1. Does it has built in REST APIs?
2. Can it access through web to configure it?
3. Can client access it through services?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it has a [REST API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj9guCKsZr1AhUMEcAKHeXtCugQFnoECBMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdynamics365%2Ffin-ops-core%2Fdev-itpro%2Fdata-entities%2Fdata-management-api&usg=AOvVaw13jK6n0Vm4PlAJB7Ptx2Mu)
2. Yes, [it can be accessed through web](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiZxtfFspr1AhVrQ0EAHbh9C6IQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdynamics365%2Ffin-ops-core%2Fdev-itpro%2Fdata-entities%2Fodata&usg=AOvVaw1hX4f5QX7tN0yMq0MLXBYO). May you elaborate the configuration you intend to do.
3. Yes, you can create [custom services](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi6l_Hcspr1AhWLYMAKHcmGCPcQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdynamics365%2Ffin-ops-core%2Fdev-itpro%2Fdata-entities%2Fcustom-services&usg=AOvVaw3uW4BU5MUTJQPTSYIBS4Gx) to interact with it or use Odata integration.

I hope this answers you.